# C# API Example for interfacing with Trello

Tags: api, trello

I know there are many people who have written C# project to interface with Trello's API, but I can't find any good examples. I'm a decent developer, but have not done any api/async work.

Is there anyone willing to share a stubbed out c# solution does few simple operations?  Create a card, archive a card...  I need some help, paid or not.

Comment: A simple Google search provided me with this: [Manatee.Trello](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Manatee.Trello/), you can add this as a Nuget package into your solution.

Comment: It works for the most part, but after updates to Trello's api has caused some functions not to work.  Same for trellonet and trellonet47.  I worked on trellonet last night, there's a bug I can't figure out.  When you create a card the card object is supposed to be returned.  It's null.  This is necessary to add labels, a due date, and position.  I think I need to write my own interface.  8(

Comment: Have you debugged the call? Try making the request in Postman or some other API testing tool and see what kind of response you get. The project is open source so you can always pull the source code off of GitHub.

Comment: @RyanWilson Manatee.Trello wont be continued. Also has memory leaks...